# display images from database

Tags: php, sql, database

How do you display an image from a SQL database in php.

The file name is stored in the database and the images itself is saved in my images file.
The image should change accordingly and correspond to the information I want.

Tried using this codes but failed

`echo"<tr><td> <img src='mysql_query('SELECT imagefile FROM recipe WHERE recipeid = $recipeid')'> </td>";`

Comment: Your question is too broad. What have you tried and what problems are you having?

Comment: 1) write some code 2) if code not done yet, see #1

Comment: @dan08 Tired with this codes but images could not be shown.    echo"<tr><td> <img src='mysql_query('SELECT imagefile FROM recipe WHERE recipeid = $recipeid')'> </td>";

Comment: oh, so you do have some code?  Edit you question and show us what you've got.

Comment: ^ Any code you have is much better in the question itself - it does not render well in comments (and one line of code is probably not enough anyway).

Comment: @user3479671 added codes..

Comment: there's so much wrong here I'm not sure where to begin: it should be more like <?php $query = mysql_query("SELECT imagefile FROM recipe WHERE recipeid = '$recipeid'");  $row  = mysql_fetch_assoc($query); $imagefile = $row['imagefile'];  echo"<tr><td> <img src='" . $imagefile . "'></td></tr>";             with a line break after each semicolon

Comment: and btw, don't use mysql because it's officially deprecated.  Switch over to mysqli before you get too far into it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a php file called image.php and an extra parameter which corresponds to the path.

Like, for example `image.php?v=007`

Hence, image.php should be able to look up the database using 007 as a reference and find it's path.

Path can be stored in a column in the database.

EDIT:

Create a php file called image.php

Next create a database with with columns like ID, REFERENCE AND PATH.

Use the following code to get the reference:

```
$reference = $_GET["v"];
```

Next look up the database for the path:

```
$stat = $conn -> prepare ("SELECT PATH FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE REFERENCE = :reference");
$stat -> bindValue(':reference', $reference);
$stat -> execute();
$path = $stat -> fetchColumn();

// Now you can use this code to display the image.

echo '<img src="' . $path . '">';
```

It will take the user to the image's path.

For this, you need to insert reference and path into the database everytime where a new image is uploaded.